# Getting desired XML Structure using Apex Webservice

Tags: apex, webservices, apex-webservice

I have a inbound webservice written in Apex. When I am generating the WSDL file and validating the Request XML format I see a flat XML structure. This is not what am expecting. I would like to have the below structure, this am not sure how can I code to achieve this in my inbound webservice. In the below structure, there can be multiple accounts and there corresponding contacts in the list.
I have also mentioned the couple of ways have tried on the class but it doesn't give the below structure what would be you advice?

```
<listAccount>
    <account>
        <AccountID>123</AccountID>
       <AccRating>A</AccRating>
    <Contact>
        <ContactId>234</ContactId>
        <FullName>Henry</FullName>
        <Email>H@gmail.com</Email>
    </contact>
    </account>
    <account>
        <AccountID>893</AccountID>
       <AccRating>A</AccRating>
    <Contact>
        <ContactId>294</ContactId>
        <FullName>Henry1</FullName>
        <Email>H1@gmail.com</Email>
    </contact>
    </account>
</ListAccount>

Instead am getting either of the below structure:

<listAccount>
<AccountID/>
<AccRating/>
</listAccount> 
or 
<Contact>
<ContactId/>
<FullName/>
<Email/>
</Contact>
```

I tried to modify my webservice as below: and it keeps failing

```
global class AccounContact
{
      global class AccountMsgSendToSF
      {
         webservice AccountID ;
         webservice AccRating; 

    global Class ContactMsgSendtoSF       
    {
         webservice ID ContactId
         webservice string FullName;
             webservice string EMail;   
    }

      }
webservice static method () {}
}
```

OR

if i try the below way: it just hides the Contact section from the XML structure

```
global class AccounContact
{
      global class AccountMsgSendToSF
      {
         webservice AccountID ;
         webservice AccRating; 
        ContactMsgSendtoSF Csf = new ContactMsgSendtoSF();

      }

global Class ContactMsgSendtoSF       
    {
         webservice ID ContactId
         webservice string FullName;
             webservice string EMail;   
    }

webservice static method () {}

}
```

Comment: @Mark Pond: Am not able to figure this out. I know using SOQL i can do cross obj query and generate the hierarchical structure. But in here its a inbound message for sales force and i would like to achieve this hierarchy. Any advice would be helpful. Also here we are not getting any WSDL from external system-we will be giving the wsdl.

Comment: Where have you defined classes that represent the nodes in your XML for ListAccount, Account, and Contact? What is the resulting XML structure that either one of your class definitions generate? What nodes are in it?

Comment: @markPond : listAccount : is a list Object of  AccountMsgSendToSF passed to webservice static method .  Contact is the list object of ContactMsgSendtoSF . I am unable to arrange these object variable in the hierachy i want them to.If i pass them individually to the static webservice method-they give me a flat structure,not the one i need

Comment: ... and what is the XML structure that either one of your class definitions generate right now? (edit your question and show the result)

Comment: @marl pond: done,edited the question to show the result am getting.T

Comment: @MarkPond: Thanks again. Helped,now need to fit and see how i can work this logic in my case.In my case-the request xml is like your soap response which we will consume and response would just tell them if its success/failure. But atleast now have an idea to go about.Will try my way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your provided code isn't valid and can not produce either one of the examples which you demonstrated as results of what is generated. It's a lot easier to assist when you provide a reproducible problem.

Below is a working example that supports the structure you're intending and also demonstrates the service payload. Hopefully you can adapt it to your needs.

**Apex**

```
global class AccountContact {

    global class AccountMsgSendToSF {
        webservice ID AccountID;
        webservice String AccRating; 
        webservice ContactMsgSendToSF contact;
    }

    global class ContactMsgSendtoSF {
        webservice ID ContactId;
        webservice string FullName;
        webservice string EMail;
    }

    global class AccountContactResponse {
        webservice AccountListType accountList;
    }

    global class AccountListType {
        webservice List<AccountMsgSendToSF> account;
    }

    webservice static AccountContactResponse getData() {

        AccountContactResponse response = new AccountContactResponse();

        AccountListType aType = new AccountListType();
        aType.account = new List<AccountMsgSendToSF>();

        // account and a contact
        AccountMsgSendToSF item = new AccountMsgSendToSF();
        item.AccountId = '001000000000000000';
        item.AccRating = 'Great';

        ContactMsgSendToSF c = new ContactMsgSendToSF();
        c.ContactId = '003000000000000000';
        c.FullName = 'Little Bobby Tables';
        c.Email = 'btables@xkcd.net';
        item.contact = c; 

        aType.account.add(item);

        // just an account
        AccountMsgSendToSF item2 = new AccountMsgSendToSF();
        item2.AccountId = '001000000000000001';
        item2.AccRating = 'Greater';
        aType.account.add(item2);

        // just an account
        AccountMsgSendToSF item3 = new AccountMsgSendToSF();
        item3.AccountId = '001000000000000002';
        item3.AccRating = 'Greatest';
        aType.account.add(item3);

        response.accountList = aType;

        // return the data payload
        return response;
    } 
}
```

**getData() SOAP Response**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/AccountContact" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <getDataResponse>
         <result>
            <accountList>
               <account>
                  <AccountID>001000000000000000</AccountID>
                  <AccRating>Great</AccRating>
                  <contact>
                     <ContactId>003000000000000000</ContactId>
                     <EMail>btables@xkcd.net</EMail>
                     <FullName>Little Bobby Tables</FullName>
                  </contact>
               </account>
               <account>
                  <AccountID>001000000000000001</AccountID>
                  <AccRating>Greater</AccRating>
                  <contact xsi:nil="true"/>
               </account>
               <account>
                  <AccountID>001000000000000002</AccountID>
                  <AccRating>Greatest</AccRating>
                  <contact xsi:nil="true"/>
               </account>
            </accountList>
         </result>
      </getDataResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```